# Clear duplicated Query String values asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I want to create and name a folder with the values from a query string. For example:

```
api/controller?lotid=value&operation=value
```

After debugging the application (as shown below) I realized that every request I tested became a collection. As a result, I suspect the folder is named `(Collection)_(Collection)` instead of the query string values  `lotid_operation`.

Any idea why this happened?

This is how I get the queries in the controller file

```
public string Get(string lotid, string operation) {
    //Secrets
}
```

Here I create the folder name

```
string folderName = lotid + "_" + operation;
```

and the how the AbsoluteUri looks in the debugger panel

```
http://localhost:5000/api/otdash?lotid=XBSs&operation=xhr1&lotid=S23B&operation=xhr1&lotid=SWB45&operation=xhr1&lotid=SWB556&operation=34s&lotid=SD23&operation=xhr1&lotid=322&operation=3sl&lotid=%27sdfa%27&operation=%27ada%27&lotid=%27SWBT12010%27&operation=%27xhr1%27&lotid=%27SWEB000%27&operation=%27xhr1&lotid=%27RESS0292%27&operation=%27das%27&lotid=SBBB&operation=sasc&lotid=%27ssss%27&operation=%27A34%27
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Especially if you're using something like a 4 point font.

Comment: you are sending multiple values with name and value pair. can you try with single values for lotid and operation ?

Comment: Please provide the code as text not image, as @itsme86 said, unfortunately `https` filtered here and I can't see the images even with VPN !!.

Comment: I do not understand people who post images like that. To me it's easier to copy and past code, rather than take a screenshot, then crop it, or to use some tool to crop only desired part, then save it and then attach it here.

Comment: If I understand that last image, you appear to have the same parameter specified multiple times in the URI. By design, this creates a collection in the request. It would help if you posted full code snippets, not images...

Comment: If you post the code not image I promise you get up votes as first technical question of yours !! and that down votes get undo, we are still waiting for your edit.

Comment: When did copy past became harder than croped screen shoot ? And thelast one is so small.. Do you accept answer in the following format a picture of me holding the answer printed on a paper,.. and for the darktheme lets say I took them at night with dim light ? That would be a really not productive way right? So why do you deny use the privilege of copy pasting even a basic line of code to make a productive answer?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I did not post the code, and thanks for letting me know.  @Nikki9696 I do not know why the parameter of the query became multiple times. I run the app many times to test, but never wrote the parameters like that.